# After installing Ubuntu 18.04 the touchpad randomly moves

Tags: 18.04, mouse, touchpad, synaptics

After installing Ubuntu 18.04 in a PC that previously had Ubuntu 20.04 working without problems, now, after the installation is complete the touchpad cursor moves randomly and opens menus etc. The only way to "calm it down" is to start using the touchpad - then it follows my directions- but when the touchpad is not touched , the random behavior starts again.

The PC is ASUS.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#2004

Comment: Why would you install 18.04 if 20.04 was working without problem?

Comment: requirements of my work. (There is a program from a well-known company that only works in 18.04 and they don't have plans to release a 20.04 version for now)

Answer (score 0):

Install and start `gnome-tweaks` and check this setting...

[image]

Comment: Yes, the settings are like that. Unfortunately this does not solve the problem. Strangely yesterday when I boot it with a USB inserted the problem dissapeared

Comment: @KansaiRobot What version USB did you boot to? That means there's a problem with your regular Ubuntu installation. Do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and then go to the ASUS web site and see if there's a newer BIOS available. Have you made any changes to xorg? Probably best to just reinstall Ubuntu then.

Comment: @KansaiRobot Status please...

Comment: the only change I made to the bios was the order of boot, meaning that now it can boot from USB. In the end, the PC needs a reboot immediately after booting up for the first time for this strange behavior to dissapear

Comment: @KansaiRobot Did you check your BIOS, as per my previous comment?

Comment: The response is `UX360UA.300`

Comment: @KansaiRobot I need the EXACT model # of your ASUS so I can check for a newer BIOS for you.